# New drive Poweredge T340

Tags: dell-poweredge

Maybe a dumb question. In order to install a extra 3.5" drive I must shutdown the server and install? Or can I pop-out a front bay and install while powered on? And later format the new drive.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your disk controller, there are three options;

H330 - its specs specifically states it can handle hot-swap/insertion.
H730p - there's no mention in its specs if it does hot-swap/insertion at all for some reason.
HBA330 - I can't find the specs at all (!) but the shared '330' bit of its name suggests it might/should work.

Hope this helps.